# Using react-router with an href button

Tags: javascript, html, react-router

I just started with reactjs and I don't quite seem to understand how to use it with buttons. So I got these two buttons here

```
  <a className="button is-warning">
  Sign up
  </a>

  <a className="button is-warning">
  Login
  </a>
```

And I want them to link to

```
<Route path="/account" component={Account}/>
<Route path="/start" component={Start}/>
```

I know there are already quite a few questions and answers about this topic here and I also watched tutorials and try to figure it out, but still I can't seem to get into my head how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<Link>` instead of `<a>`

```
<Link to="/account" className="button is-warning">Sign up</Link>
<Link to="/start" className="button is-warning">Login</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to use the  component but that was throwing some error (don't remember which errors) but then I just tried to use the  from react-router-dom and it worked like a charm.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).